# Flask - How to store a value accessible among all blueprints

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

How can I use a value created by an outside program before starting of the `flask` run?

If it is not possible then how can a variable which gets assigned in `__init__.py`at the start of flask app be used inside files which are registered through `blueprint.register`?

Ex:

`__init__.py`

```
   var1 = "SOMETHING"
```

`routes.py`

```
  if var1 = "SOMETHING":
     call api1 
  else
     call api2
```

Basically the question is: How to share variables between `__init__.py` and those `*.py` files which are connected through `blueprint`.

Comment: I never tested but how about using `app.config["var1"] = "SOMETHING"` ? Or maybe when you use `Blueprint()` then add these values as arguments ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way. But it gives error " app" not found. Please remember that I am trying to use this config value inside dl_routes.py which is added using  blueprint.register() method.  How to make `app` accessible inside `dl_routes.py` ?

Comment: @Gsb Inside a blueprint, you use current_app, not app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practice is to use environmental variables for such purposes. 
On unix systems you can easily set variable by another utility using:

```sh
export VARIABLE="SOMETHING"
```

Then you can access such variable in your code in following way:

```py
os.getenv("VARIABLE", "some default value")
```

Consequently, your example would look like below:

```py
import os

var1 = os.getenv("VARIABLE", "SOMETHING ELSE")
if var1 = "SOMETHING":
   call api1 
else
   call api2
```

You can find more details how to use environmental variables with flask in its documentation:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/

---

The advantage of using environmental variables is ease of providing configuration for your application in containerized environments e.g. in kubernetes or docker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am now using `os.environ['VAR1'] = 'SOMETHING' ` inside main `__init__.py`  and in my `dl_routes.py` took the value back by using `current_var = os.getenv('VAR1') ` . The problem is each time the function inside `dl_routes.py` is called, `os.getenv()` function is executed.  But is there any way to avoid calling this `os.getenv()` each time? Is there a way to set a variable inside main `__init__.py` and later use it inside `dl_routes.py` as a variable like a **one-time** variable assignment?